# How to find the specific `*Release` apt state information file for a given package?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, unattended-upgrades

I need to programmatically gather the apt `Origin` and `Suite` information for a certain package, in order to configure `unattended-upgrades`.

I can manually find the corresponding apt state information file, then process it, however, I need to automated the process.

For example, if I:

- add the PPA `ppa:qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable`
- install `qbittorrent-nox`

among the other files, apt will create `/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_qbittorrent-team_qbittorrent-stable_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease`, which is the file I'm looking for.

I've tried with `apt-cache showpkg`:

```sh
$ apt-cache showpkg qbittorrent-nox
Package: qbittorrent-nox
Versions:
4.1.7.99~201908140017-6718-e98f44a~ubuntu16.04.1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_qbittorrent-team_qbittorrent-stable_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-armhf_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
[...]
```

which doesn't include the `_InRelease` file.

Is there an exact programmatic way to find the `*Release` file name, starting from the package, or even better, there `Origin` and `Suite` values?

Edit: extra output follows:

```
$ apt-cache policy qbittorrent-nox  
qbittorrent-nox:
  Installed: 4.1.7.99~201908140017-6718-e98f44a~ubuntu16.04.1
  Candidate: 4.1.7.99~201908140017-6718-e98f44a~ubuntu16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 4.1.7.99~201908140017-6718-e98f44a~ubuntu16.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu xenial/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.3.1-1 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe armhf Packages
```

```sh
$ grep -r armhf /etc/apt --include="*.list"
# nothing
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy qbittorrent-nox` and `grep -r armhf /etc/apt --include="*.list"` to the question. Having *armhf* on *amd64* (desktop or laptop machine) will mean that you have wrong line in your `sources.list`.

Comment: Ubuntu also has arm distributions :-)  The output comes from an armv7l host. I've added the requested commands' output, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the research I've done, there is no direct way to solve this problem.

However, according to the [Debian repository format document](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format), the naming of the state information files has precise rules, that can be used.

Therefore, one can find a package's `_Packages` corresponding filename via `apt-cache showpkg`, then process it according to the repository format rules:

- if the respository has a component, the name will have a suffix `_<component>_binary-<arch>_Packages`
- otherwise, the suffix will be just `_Packages`

then:

- replace the suffix with `_InRelease`, and test the resulting filename
- if the file exists, all done
- if not, replace the suffix with `Release` (which is an alternative naming for state files with an external signature)